# Adding custom text to the lockscreen

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have an app I made that will display what percent my battery is at (the 32 in the notification bar). I am wondering is it possible to add that information to the lockscreen (maybe under the time, but anywhere would work)? I know I can change the "I can see you" text via Settings -> General -> Screen lock -> Owner info (I am running Android 4.1.1), but I wouldn't be able to update that with the battery percent.  From what I can gather I would need to write my own lock screen and add it there. Is that true or is there another way?

[image: Where I would like information added]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to write [an app widget that can be placed on the lockscreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen), for Android 4.2+.

Comment: Hmm okay, but there isn't a way for it for Android 4.1?

Comment: @20040922: No, sorry.

Comment: Only Android versions lower than 5.0 support lock-screen widgets. For Android 5.0 and higher, only home_screen is valid. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html